# How can I get the correct resolution with an Aspeed graphics controller under Debian?

Tags: debian, x11, xorg, graphics

I've installed Debian 10.6 with the Mate desktop. The motherboard has an onboard graphics controller with an Aspeed chipset.

```
 lspci | grep VGA
45:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family (rev 41)


45:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family (rev 41) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 59, NUMA node 0
    Memory at b0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at b1000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at 9000 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/2 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: ast
```

I've installed the `xserver-xorg-video-ast` package (which supposedly has the driver), and it appears that the driver is actually in use, per:

```
Kernel driver in use: ast
```

But on the monitor resolution selection dialog, I only have three options that range from 800x600 to 1024x768. The monitor connected should run at 1920x1080.

How do I get the option to set it to 1920x1080?

Comment: Which specific chip does the system have? `sudo dmesg` will tell you what the kernel detected — look for “AST .... detected”. Some AST chips don’t support any widescreen modes, which limits the available resolutions on modern monitors.

Comment: @StephenKitt `[    3.390424] [drm] AST 2500 detected`

Answer (score 1):

If you run `sudo dmesg |grep firmware`, do you find an error message about missing firmware file `ast_dp501_fw.bin`?

Some Aspeed graphics controllers (at least the Aspeed AST 2400 on my system) seem to require this firmware file to run at full resolution/widescreen modes. Apparently AST has not granted a license to redistribute this firmware file (in binary form?) at the [Linux-firmware git repository.](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/)

Supermicro has [a FAQ entry referring to that firmware file](https://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=26876) and a [Google drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rBp3z_4_LNmx8ci_U4VAL5-qB4sjM-aV/view?usp=sharing) to the firmware file. Download at your own risk.

If you choose to use this file, place it on your system as `/lib/firmware/ast_dp501_fw.bin`, and then update your initramfs file (e.g. `sudo update-initramfs -u` in Debian/Ubuntu and related distributions) so the firmware file gets added in initramfs. The kernel driver for the display controller gets loaded very early in the boot sequence, and it looks for the firmware file while the system is still running on initramfs.

Also, the message `Kernel driver in use: ast` only identifies the **kernel** driver. You should read `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` to see which **userspace driver** the X server ends up using. It might be using a generic VGA/SVGA driver instead of the `xserver-xorg-video-ast` driver. If so, you might need to add a configuration snippet to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` to force the correct driver to be used.

Update: [Looks like the license-to-redistribute issue has been solved since then.](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-video-ast/-/blob/master/src/ast_dp501fw.h?ref_type=heads)

```
 * Copyright (c) 2005 ASPEED Technology Inc.
 *
 * Permission to use, copy, modify, distribute, and sell this software and its
 * documentation for any purpose is hereby granted without fee, provided that
 * the above copyright notice appear in all copies and that both that
 * copyright notice and this permission notice appear in supporting
 * documentation, and that the name of the authors not be used in
 * advertising or publicity pertaining to distribution of the software without
 * specific, written prior permission. 
[...]
```

Daniel Baumann's upstream repository includes a Makefile that can reproduce the `ast_dp501_fw.bin` file from the clearly redistributable `ast_dp501_fw.h`.

https://git.progress-linux.org/users/daniel.baumann/debian/packages/firmware-ast

Comment: Looks like Debian has `ast_dp501_fw.bin` in the [`firmware-ast`](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/firmware-ast) package, though that *is* in the `non-free-firmware` archive.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Aspeed 2500 but I have experience on Aspeed 2600 with AOC 1440x900 monitor.

After upgrading my PC mainboard with the Aspeed 2600, I found that the Aspeed driver does not detect VESA correctly with 16:9 resolution, all available modes are 4:3, so I tried to add it manually and it's working. Not perfectly, some things look strange on physical display (Ubuntu 20.04, same screen via Vino VNC viewer connected from another PC does not have this issue).

```
xrandr --newmode "1440x900_59.90"  106.29  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 901 904 932  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1440x900_59.90
```

It may be a hint to resolve your problem.